# GDAX api, dictionaries and request class

Tags: python

I am a complete novice at Python but have coded basic things in the past. I a looking to code some relatively simple trailing stop loss code. I am using the [GDAX docs](https://docs.gdax.com/) and the guide at [Cryptostag](https://cryptostag.com/basic-gdax-api-trading-with-python/) and have managed to get some of it working. I think I should be ok with the actual algorithm to place orders at the right time but need help with the api and extracting information.

Problem 1:

```
`lorder = requests.get(api_base + '/orders/' + 'f39d35ec-ba7e-49ed-a21e-d78a8168907c', auth=auth)
print (lorder.json())`
```

This results in {'message': 'invalid signature'}. But I can't think why.

Problem 2:
`accts = requests.get(api_base + 'accounts', auth=auth)`

Returns

[{'id': '16d672da-b3eb-4e42-bfc2-da0c8e788fa8', 'currency': 'LTC', 'balance': '0.1234567000000000', 'available': '0.2931758', 'hold': '0.6000000000000000', 'profile_id': '172f7b0b-16b2-3b81-a92f-b7ac1ad253df'}, {'id': '430025c7-0109-4167-739c-15324cfabd8c', 'currency': 'EUR', 'balance': '120.6713649805422500', 'available': '012.14336468054225', 'hold': '324.5280000000000000', 'profile_id': '373f8b0b-18b2-4b71-a91f-b9ac6ad243df'}, {'id': '53d4403f-ea07-47c9-87dd-fa3bf887a5a2', 'currency': 'BTC', 'balance': '0.0087190400000000', 'available': '0.00871904', 'hold': '0.0000000000000000', 'profile_id': '172f7b0b-16b2-3b81-a92f-b7ac1ad253df'}, {'id': '1a25b6a9-90cd-4205-ac18-960cd6e1e50e', 'currency': 'GBP', 'balance': '0.0000000000000000', 'available': '0', 'hold': '0.0000000000000000', 'profile_id': '172f7b0b-16b2-3b81-a92f-b7ac1ad253df'}, {'id': '35470e2c-de36-93ea-8716-c35c34bg92e7', 'currency': 'ETH', 'balance': '0.6582615200000000', 'available': '0.50886152', 'hold': '0.1600000000000000', 'profile_id': '172f7b0b-16b2-3b81-a92f-b7ac1ad253df'}, {'id': '0da4e6cb-9017-817e-1ec6-1dce37fba867', 'currency': 'BCH', 'balance': '0.0000000000000000', 'available': '0', 'hold': '0.0000000000000000', 'profile_id': '172f7b0b-16b2-3b81-a92f-b7ac1ad253df'}]

`type(accts)`

returns `<class 'requests.models.Response'>`

I tried:

```
caccts = accts.content
BTCaccts = list(filter(lambda cur: cur['currency'] == 'BTC', caccts))
```

However, I am getting: TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable.

I have also tried caccts = accts.text but that doesn't work either.

Thanks

Comment: The IDs etc. have been changed by the way.

Comment: Ignore problem 2, worked it out. Thanks